# Delete Specific Image According to Id created dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file, session

I got a quick question. I am displaying images in a specific session directory through PHP and also deleting them, problem is, the script deletes all of the images not just one of them. Here is what I'm doing:

PHP/HTML:

```
<ul class="image-list">
        <?php
        if ($_SESSION['curHotelId']) {
            $count = 1;
            foreach(glob('assets/php/upload/'.$_SESSION['curHotelId'].'/*') as $filename){
                echo '<li id="del'.$count.'" class="image-list"><img src="'.$filename.'" width="50px" height="50px"/><p class="filename">' . basename($filename) . '</p> <a class="btn btn-mini btn-primary image-list" style="width: 50px; margin-top:-20px;" id="del'.$count.'" value="Delete">remove</a></li>' . "\n" . "<br>";
                $count++;
            }
        }else {}
        ?>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('ul li a.image-list').live('click', function() { 
    var answer =  confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this image?');
    if (answer) {
    $.post('assets/php/deletefile.php');
    $(this).closest('.li').remove();
    }
});
```

Delete Script:

```
<?php 
session_start();
    foreach(glob("upload/" . $_SESSION['curHotelId'] . "/" . '*.*') as $file)
        if(is_file($file))
            @unlink($file);
?>
```

Anything helps!

Comment: This is because you are using `*.*` in your `glob()`.  What do you expect would happen?  You are not making any attempt to send the specific filename to be deleted at all as POST data.

Comment: Your `glob` command searches for this: `'*.*'`. That's **every** file in the folder. Then it deletes everything it finds.

Comment: I'm aware that is what it does. I put it there as a placeholder because I do not know how to get to the specific file. I apologize for doing so, I thought it was clear that was what I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove only one (first) file in current session folder:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$files = glob("upload/" . $_SESSION['curHotelId'] . "/" . '*.*');

if(is_file($files[0]))
    @unlink($files[0]);

?>
```

Comment: @Ross yes, sorry, fixed it.